# Sql query to identify running previous row value and do some computations

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Following is the dataset contains `original_date` and `priority` columns. The query to identify the output based on some conditions. Conditions are mentioned below

**Logic:**

If the previous and current date difference from the original date column is less than 4 minutes and priority is greater than 2 then add 4 minutes to the original date.

**Note**: this new output date will be the previous date for the next row calculations.

Facing hard time to populate the output based on the the above conditions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_sev
(
    original_date TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    priority varchar
);

INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 14:45:00', 2);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 14:46:41', 3);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 14:47:13', 4);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 14:51:38', 3);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 14:51:46', 4);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 15:05:50', 1);
INSERT INTO test_sev VALUES ('7/29/2021 15:13:50', 4);
```

Input dataset:

[image: input]

Query used:

```
WITH DATA1 AS
(
    SELECT
        original_date,
        LAG(original_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY original_date) AS prev_original_date,
        DATEDIFF('minute', prev_original_date, original_date) AS TIME_DIFF,
        CASE 
            WHEN priority > 2 AND TIME_DIFF < 4 
                THEN DATEADD ('minute', 4, prev_original_date) 
                ELSE original_date 
        END AS new_original_date,
        priority
    FROM 
        test_sev
)
SELECT
    original_date, priority, new_original_date 
FROM 
    DATA1;
```

Output I get:

[image: Output Received:]

**Issue**: rows number 3, 4 and 5 are wrong. It is not getting the previous date from the running `new_original_date`.

Correct output:

[image]

Could you please help with the correct query. Appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Your query works according to the logic you want. The output you want does not make sense.

Comment: Which database are you really using?  Remove the other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated with SQL for MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.5*

I couldn't guess your database, nor did any support your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Since you tagged MySQL, I decided to just make the necessary changes to run with that database (and MariaDB).

One problem in your SQL is the standard and most databases do not support accessing a derived column in the same `SELECT` list.  Normally, we would need to place the expression in a derived table or CTE term and then refer to the derived column in the outer (or subsequent) query expression.

An alternative is to use the original expression instead of the derived column name, as needed.

Here's an example of your SQL in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.5 using this approach (**updated to use recursion**):

SQL for MySQL/MariaDB:

```
WITH RECURSIVE data1 ( original_date, priority, seq ) AS (
          SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY original_date) FROM test_sev AS t
     )
   , data0 ( original_date, prev_original_date, priority, new_original_date, seq ) AS (
          SELECT original_date, CAST(null AS DATETIME), priority, original_date, seq FROM data1 WHERE seq = 1 UNION ALL
          SELECT d1.original_date
               , d0.new_original_date
               , d1.priority
               , CASE
                    WHEN d1.priority > 2
                     AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, d0.new_original_date, d1.original_date) < 4
                    THEN d0.new_original_date + INTERVAL '4' MINUTE
                    ELSE d1.original_date
                 END AS new_orig
               , d1.seq
            FROM data1 AS d1
            JOIN data0 AS d0
              ON d1.seq = d0.seq+1
     )
SELECT * FROM data0
;
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------+
| original_date       | prev_original_date  | priority | new_original_date   | seq  |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------+
| 2021-07-29 14:45:00 | NULL                | 2        | 2021-07-29 14:45:00 |    1 |
| 2021-07-29 14:46:41 | 2021-07-29 14:45:00 | 3        | 2021-07-29 14:49:00 |    2 |
| 2021-07-29 14:47:13 | 2021-07-29 14:49:00 | 4        | 2021-07-29 14:53:00 |    3 |
| 2021-07-29 14:51:38 | 2021-07-29 14:53:00 | 3        | 2021-07-29 14:57:00 |    4 |
| 2021-07-29 14:51:46 | 2021-07-29 14:57:00 | 4        | 2021-07-29 15:01:00 |    5 |
| 2021-07-29 15:05:50 | 2021-07-29 15:01:00 | 1        | 2021-07-29 15:05:50 |    6 |
| 2021-07-29 15:13:50 | 2021-07-29 15:05:50 | 4        | 2021-07-29 15:13:50 |    7 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------+
```

[Working Test Case for MySQL and MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a97de9c01f037d089ea26560edaccf08)

Comment: Thanks for attempting Jon. This is the same output what I have got with my query too. If you look in to the row 3,4 and 5 it is not correct. The actual value should be the previous running row [new_orginal_date] plus 4 minutes.

Comment: @Ansip I guess I misunderstood.  Are you saying you want a "kind of running adjustment"?  That can be done recursively.  If that's correct, I'll take a shot at it in a moment.

Comment: Yes that's correct, running adjustment needs to happen for this logic

Comment: @Ansip See my updated answer.  It produces the required result, using recursive CTE.

Comment: @Ansip You tagged MySQL, so I used MySQL in the answer.  If you are using a different database, this can be adjusted as needed.  You haven't responded to that question, however.  Most of the major databases support this.

Comment: You are a champ. This really works. Initially I had checked your comments only. Sorry for that. I am using snowflake and it supports derived column in the same select query. What changes you are suggesting to do if that feature supports. As this is recursive it is bit confusing to me... Thank you Jon.

Comment: @Ansip I made one further adjustment.  But it's essentially the same SQL for both MySQL and MariaDB.  This may translate fairly simply to snowflake.  I just don't have access to an instance to try.

Comment: @Ansip If this is an acceptable answer, don't forget to, you know, *accept* it.  :)

Comment: @Ansip Would you like to chat about recursive logic in SQL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236030/discussion-between-ansip-and-jon-armstrong).

Comment: I did encountered an issue when I executed with the bigger dataset.. Recursion exceeded max iteration count (2000)
Seems the recursion iteration has a maximum limit in Snowflake..

Comment: @Ansip For MySQL and MariaDB, that's configurable, system wide and per session.  Not sure how snowflake handles that.  I think the default is 1000, for MySQL, with a maximum of probably around 2 billion within a factor of 2.

Comment: @Ansip Worst case, you could run the query iteratively, each time starting where the last run left off.  To cover 1M rows, you would need to run this ~500 times.  I would first check that the limit is really 2000 max.  That might just be a default setting which is changeable.

Comment: I have verified already but unfortunately no way we can change the default settings in Snowflake. Is there a way we can run this query automatically with the last run left off values. Thanks

Comment: @Ansip Use one CTE term to assign row_number to each row ordered by date. Add another CTE term that generates a list of numbers from 1 to `COUNT` of rows in your set, in increments of 1000 (1, 1001, 2001, etc, to n).  Now use that list to drive/derive the root rows in your recursive CTE logic.  Make sure your termination logic includes a max depth of 1000.  Done.  One execution to do it all, but none of the recursive searches (iterations) will go beyond 1000.  Let me know if you need more hints... or just ask a new question: "How to avoid a database limit on recursion depth."  It's simple.

Comment: Thank you for the steps and logic. Really appreciate.